# prevent xml entity expansion attack with jaxb2marshaller

Tags: spring, jaxb

I have looked at @BlaiseDoughan's blog entry [Preventing Entity Expansion Attacks in JAXB](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/preventing-entity-expansion-attacks-in.html), and I am trying to look at ways to prevent XMLentity expansion attacks while parsing incoming web service calls using Spring's `Jaxb2Marshaller`.

How can I configure the `XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` into its parsers?
Or should I set `-DentityExpansionLimit=0`?

Comment: Did you read the blog article properly?  It says "Since the secure processing feature is enabled by default, the JAXB implementation you are using should already be protected from this type of attack. "